# Unable to initialize variables in constructor in a class in angular 4 project

Tags: angular

this is my app.component.ts file in angular 4 project.

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  submitted = false;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  private generateOtp(): void {
    // this.dataService.create(this.customer);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.generateOtp();
  }
}
```

While initializing dataservice variable or any other variable in constructor i'm getting this following error in browser console

```
fileName: "http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js line 569 > eval"
lineNumber: 1208
message: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> DataService]: \n  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> DataService]: \n    NullInjectorError: No provider for DataService!"
```

Comment: You don't show where you define and provide `DataService`, so... have you correctly defined and provided it? Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I think your forgot define your service as a provider in your App.module.ts file.

In the Provider section add DataService an try build again

Comment: Now I defined but still I'm facing sqme error @Leo R.